# Get a query and it's parameters values from VS in debugger for calling into SQL

Tags: visual-studio, ado.net

Is there a way by not manually copy each statement like a SELECT or stored procedure and it's parameters values in debugger mode for executing it into SQL environment? I'm thinking of a box displaying the entire statement in Visual Studio and just copy it's content.

it is inconvenient to copy parameter's values for a query that has 20 parameters by checking each argument.

Comment: Intellitrace displays SQL events. 20 parameters are a bit too much though. Sounds like you are using a stored procedure instead of an INSERT or UPDATE statement? Perhaps SqlBulkCopy would be a better option?

Answer (score 0):

With a profiler you can obtain the exact command executed in the DB. For example, using "SQL Server 2016 Profiler" you get the following for a SQL query with two parameters:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE customerId=@Param1 AND productId=@Param2',N'@Param1 int,@Param2 int',@Param1=30,@Param2=10
```

This command can be executed in SSMS.